# Dell 2665 colored vertical streaks

Tags: laser-printer

Our Dell 2665 printer is printing colored vertical streaks.  If a multi-page document is printed, they are worst on the first page and light to nonexistant on later pages.  They appear on every print job:
[image: Dell2665 Colored vertical streaks]

We have tried the suggestions from the [Dell troubleshooting page](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln288776/how-to-troubleshoot-print-quality-issues-on-the-c2660dn-c2665dnf-c3760n-c3760dn-c3765dnf-dell-laser-printers?lang=en#Six) of replacing low toner cartridges, replacing the transfer belts, and replacing the drum cartridges.  We also tried the raster optical scanner window cleaning suggested on [another Dell support page](http://www.dell.com/learn/us/en/rc802325/videos~en/documents~esupport-laser-printer-vertical-lines-draft-v3.aspx).  No effect from any of this.

Google turns up other users with this same issue ([1](https://www.dell.com/community/Printers/C2665-Printing-Black-Vertical-Lines/td-p/4733423), [2](https://www.dell.com/community/Printers/C2665dnf-vertical-lines-on-printout/td-p/5065218)) but no solutions.

How can we fix the printer to stop these streaks on every print job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A helpful Dell chat employee pointed me in the right direction: the [maintenance kit](http://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-c2660dn-c2665dnf-c3760n-c3760dn-c3765dnf-maintenance-kit-belt-unit-2nd-btr-and-cst-retard-roller-100k-100000-pg-yield-part-7xdtm-sku-331-8956/apd/331-8956/printers-ink-toner) for this printer completely eliminated the streaks and also the sporadic faded colors.

The kit is part 7XDTM, sku 331-8956, and includes "Belt Unit, 2nd BTR and CST Retard Roller".